# Script for sending mail from contact form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am trying to create a simple contact form with a PHP script to send an email. But the following script, located in the same folder as the index.html, is not working. It leads me to an 'This page is not working' page. On this URL: ipaddress/contact-form.php. Could be I am misplacing files, but do not seem to grasp what must be done.

The HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="contact-form.php" class="contact-form">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Volledige naam*</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="Name"
              placeholder="Your full name"
              required
            />
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email*</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="Email"
              placeholder="voorbeeld@hotmail.com"
              required
            />
            <label for="phone" class="form-label">Telefoonnummer</label>
            <input
              type="tel"
              name="phone"
              id="Phone"
              placeholder="06-12345667"
            />
            <label for="message" class="form-label">Bericht*</label>
            <textarea
              type="text"
              name="message"
              id="Message"
              placeholder="Uw bericht.."
              required
            ></textarea>
            <small class="required">* verplicht</small>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Verstuur</button>
          </form>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {

    $email_to = "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Een nieuw contactbericht";

    function problem($error)
    {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br><br>";
        echo $error . "<br><br>";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br><br>";
        die();
    }

    if (
        !isset($_POST['Name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Message'])
    ) {
        problem('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['Name']; 
    $email = $_POST['Email']; 
    $message = $_POST['Message']; 

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        problem($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: " . clean_string($phone) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: " . clean_string($message) . "\n";


    $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

    Bedankt voor uw bericht! We zullen zo spoedig mogelijk contact met u opnemen.

<?php
}
?>
```

Any thoughts? :)

Comment: _"This page is not working"_ ...is there an accompanying HTTP status code with the message? e.g. 404, 500, something like that?

Comment: Don't put `@` in front of function names e.g. in your `@mail...` . That just suppresses errors which might actually be useful for diagnosing problems.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is your message built properly? Is calling `mail` working properly? Is there anything written to your server's error log about this, or maybe to the server's mail log?

Comment: When I click on the Submit button, it leads me directly to an error page. Can't answer your specific questions as this PHP and forms is new to me. The console in the browser shows an error regarding; The server responded with a status of 405.

Comment: Updated the script in the post above.

Comment: Dont do that, there is an answer to the orifinal issue, if you change the question it makes a valid answer look wrong

Comment: _Small Point_ While its legal to create functions inside an IF its not good practice. Reason, if you are not insde the IF the function will not be created, you may not spot the function is dependant upon an IF. And there be dragons

Answer (score 4):

When browsers submit forms, they encode the data as a series of `name=value` pairs, **not** `id=value` pairs.

You're using the wrong keys (e.g. `$_POST['Email']` should be `$_POST['email']` because you have `name="email"`)

---

> The server responded with a status of 405

405 means Method Not Allowed.

This means that your server (whatever server that might be) is configured not to accept POST requests for that URL.

Maybe it is a server that doesn't support PHP at all.

Maybe you have the wrong URL.

Maybe the security settings for it are set to restrict request types.